# How to test actions with queue workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, resque

I have an action `create` in `UsersController` which looks like this

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    sign_in_as(@user)
    Resque.enqueue(MailWorker, @user.email)
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thanks"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Before I added `reqsue` to this action, I've been testing email confrimation like this

```
it "creates a new user account" do
  # code for creating a new account...

  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size.should == 1
  mail = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  mail.to.should == [user[:email]]
  mail.body.encoded.should match(/Thank you for registration/)
end
```

But now, since I added resque worker to deliver the message, I guess it doesn't deliver the message instantly and therefore I'm getting this test failed with the message

```
 Failure/Error: ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size.should == 1
   expected: 1
        got: 0 (using ==)
```

How can I test such cases, when async workers are involved and the result depends on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've decoupled the mail delivery from your controller, you will also be able to decouple the tests. What I've done in the past for this is use the [resque_spec Gem](https://github.com/leshill/resque_spec) which lets you add assertions for whether or not the jobs have been enqueued as expected.

You will be adding something like this in your tests:

```
MailWorker.should have_queued(user.email)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [rescue_spec](https://github.com/leshill/resque_spec) gem.